# Rail Radio Button Values Not Submitting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a should-be simple quiz in my rails app.  The model is `ManTest` and the only columns in the data table are `score` and a references relationship for `user`.  I have the form working somewhat, but it is recording the `score` as 0 regardless of the radio button selected.

My quiz is in a form partial `_test0.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for @man_test do |f| %>
    <h3>
      <%= f.label "Which can you NOT score when playing American football?" %>
      <%= f.radio_button :score, value: "1" %>Touchdown<br>
      <%= f.radio_button :score, value: "0" %>Basket<br>
      <%= f.radio_button :score, value: "1" %>Field Goal<br>
      <%= f.radio_button :score, value: "1" %>Safety</h3>
      <div class="text-center">
        <%= f.submit "Confirm I'm a Man", class: "btn-boring" %>
      </div>
    </h3>
<% end %>
```

Called like this on the `man_tests#new` page:

```
<div class="hover-well col-xs-10 col-xs-push-1 col-sm-8 col-sm-push-2">
  <h1>Answer the following question to gain entry:</h1>
  <%= render partial: 'man_tests/test00' %>
</div> <!-- hover-well -->
```

And when I do `ManTest.last` in my console I get this:

```
[3] pry(main)> ManTest.last
  ManTest Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "man_tests".* FROM "man_tests"  ORDER BY "man_tests"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<ManTest:0x007f851acabdd0
 id: 3,
 score: 0,  <<<<< SCORE IS ZERO REGARDLESS OF RADIO SELECTED
 user_id: nil,
 created_at: Sun, 03 Jul 2016 04:28:55 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Sun, 03 Jul 2016 04:28:55 UTC +00:00>
```

Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong that makes all the choices yield a score of zero?

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

Here's the schema for the `ManTest` table:

```
  create_table "man_tests", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "score"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

And here's my `man_tests_controller`:

```
class ManTestsController < ApplicationController
  layout false

  def new
    @man_test = ManTest.new
  end

  def create
    @man_test = ManTest.new(man_test_params)
    if @man_test.save && @man_test.score == 1
      redirect_to home_index_path
    elsif @man_test.save && @man_test.score == 0
      redirect_to controller: :man_tests, action: :fail
    else
      render controller: :man_tests, action: :new
    end
  end

  def fail
  end

  private

  def man_test_params
    params.require(:man_test).permit(:user, :score)
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you show your controller also? And what is the datatype of the the column `score` in your DB?

Comment: @ArupRakshit, I added the controller and the `schema` for the `man_tests` table.

Comment: When you select the radio button which value is `"1"` and submit the form, you get a log which u can see in the `log/development.log`. Can u paste that also?

Comment: @ArupRakshit, how do I access that log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the erb for the quiz and it worked like this:

```
  <%= f.label "Which can you NOT score when playing American football?" %>
  <%= f.radio_button :score, 0 %>
  <%= f.label :score, "Touchdown", value: 0 %><br>
  <%= f.radio_button :score, 1 %>
  <%= f.label :score, "Basket", value: 1 %><br>
  <%= f.radio_button :score, 0 %>
  <%= f.label :score, "Field Goal", value: 0 %><br>
  <%= f.radio_button :score, 0 %>
  <%= f.label :score, "Safety", value: 0  %><br>
```